# Why do the bars in my horizontal bar graph have different widths when I specified the same width?

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
totalDate = [11.893468038358078, 10.38214337050042, 9.955029877410214, 8.47656009363642, 8.47656009363642, 8.049446600546213, 7.7537526437914535, 7.589478223372143, 7.589478223372143, 7.39234891886897, 7.39234891886897, 6.899525657611039, 6.5709768167724185, 6.472412164520832, 6.308137744101521, 6.2095730918499354, 4.796813076243866, 4.796813076243866, 4.435409351321383, 4.40255446723752, 4.139715394566624, 4.139715394566624, 3.975440974147313, 3.219778640218485, 2.924084683463726, 2.266987001786484, 2.234132117702622, 2.234132117702622, 2.234132117702622, 1.9055832768640013, 1.8398735086962772, 1.6098893201092426, 0.722807449844966]
bar_list = plt.barh(np.arange(len(totalDate)), Reverse(totalDate), color=color, align='center', height=.4)
plt.show()
```

why do I get different widths in some parts of the graph?
[Here is the graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COAQn.png)

[Here is the graph zoomed in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2h6m.png)

As you can see from these two images, the middle bar at 25 is thinner than the ones around it even though I specified the height of each bar to be .4? Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: i dont think it really matters

Comment: When you save to image make sure you specify dpi to something higher to get better quality. You can also try to save to pdf and zoom in to see the actual width.

Comment: If you still cannot resolve it try to share the code or the process with which you exported the plot to a `png` image.

Comment: seems to be a dpi problem: I increased the dpi and several of the widths are now similar, however some are still longer widths than others! I used     plt.savefig('myplot.png', dpi=1500) to do this! Thank you!